# how can i load an external page into a div using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

i have a menu with 3 links, when the user clicks on a menu link  i want the page to load on a div on the same page using jquery, im using php and mysql!

thank you!

Comment: Is the page you want to load on the same server (Javascript prevents you to load from an external site for security reasons, so you'll need an intermediate serverside script to fetch the data from another site, which you can load using ajax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded from @jAndy's example:

Markup:

```
<a href="/foo/bar.html" id="baz">Load external html</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#baz').click(function () { $('#result').load(this.href); });
```

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#local_container').load('external/file.php #external_container');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read some docs @ [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Btw this might be your answer:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is the javascript side of things, what do i put for the hyperlink on the html page, to conect it to this snippet!! sorry im a still a newbie thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to gather information from mysql database.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'getnames.php',
  datatype: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $('#id_of_the_div').text("");
    $('#id_of_the_div').append(data.returned);
  }
});
```

in the php file:

```
//..
// commands that run mysql queries and gather information from database
//..
//..
//..
// you store what you've got from the database in a $ret variable and then:
// $ret can be for example:
// $ret = "<table><tr><td>Peter</td><td>40</td></tr></table>";

$arr = Array("returned"=>$ret);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Of course this was just an example from the several ways you can use. I've used ajax request and json...